# Why don't users with the "Create new content" permission for a custom bundle cannot access /node/add, but they can access /node/add/author?

Tags: entities, 9

If I give to a custom role the *Article: Create new content* permission, users can access the */node/add* page.  However, if I give the same permission for a custom bundle, for example *Author: Create new content*, users can't access that page, but yet can access /node/add/author.

What should I try to address the problem? I've tried to debug `NodeAccessControlHandler::createAccess()`, but this code doesn't show anything wrong.

```php
$result = parent::createAccess($entity_bundle, $account, $context, TRUE)->cachePerPermissions();
return $return_as_object ? $result : $result->isAllowed();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some test, I discovered it was due to some incompatibility between [form mode manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/form_mode_manager) and [entity limit](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_limit)